# "You can drop dockable dialogs here" in place of the image view

Tags: gimp, user-interface

I clicked or double-clicked on something and now my Gimp looks like this when I start it:

[image]

It also causes Gimp to crash if I try to open xcf images. Pasting screenshots into Gimp still works, but I can't do anything because my image is turned off. How do I get my image view back instead of this?

Comment: Nevermind. it was easier to just reinstall gimp than to try to figure this out. Only if I could in some way, ANY way get my ui back. It is attrocious trying to adjust in the ui gimp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you customize in Gimp is in the [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/).

The windows setup in in the `sessionrc` file in that profile.

You can restore the window positions to factory settings with *Edit>Preferences>Interface>Windows management>Reset window positions to default values*

Normally reinstalling doesn't solve anything since the profile is kept and reused by the newly installed instance (unless you reinstall a different version, profile locations may change between versions).

As a last resort you can rename the profile to make Gimp create a new one, and then copy things (brushes, gradients, scripts...) little by little from the old to the new.

Comment: I deleted the .gimp-2.8 from my users folder as well so I got a clean install.

Comment: A good idea is to just rename the profile to make Gimp create  a new one, and then copy things (brushes, gradients, scripts...) little by little from the old to the new.